# Freeze Graph from TensorFlow hub to use on Google Coral

Tags: keras, tensorflow-hub, google-coral, tensorflow-lite

I am trying to use Google Colab to build a model for use on a Google Coral device. In order to do this I need to freeze the Graph and then convert it to TfLite. I can successfully create the model and test it using the tutorial but I cannot figure out how to Freeze the graph.  At the end of the tutorial the model is saved in the Saved_Model format. My Google Colab notebook is available here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1F6wvz4yUp6Iz2hY3n7bQYnYBJe7H5JUE/view?usp=sharing

I have tried a variety of code samples I have found on the web but all have ended in errors. Currently I am trying this code to freeze the graph

```py
from tensorflow.python.tools import freeze_graph
from tensorflow.python.saved_model import tag_constants

input_saved_model_dir = export_path
output_node_names = "dense/Softmax"
input_binary = True
input_saver_def_path = False
restore_op_name = None
filename_tensor_name = None
clear_devices = False
input_meta_graph = False
checkpoint_path = None
input_graph_filename = None
saved_model_tags = tag_constants.SERVING
output_graph_filename = "./frozenGraph.pb"

freeze_graph.freeze_graph(input_graph_filename, input_saver_def_path,
                            input_binary, checkpoint_path, output_node_names,
                              restore_op_name, filename_tensor_name,
                              output_graph_filename, clear_devices, "", "", "",
                              input_meta_graph, input_saved_model_dir,
                            saved_model_tags)
```

But I get the error:

```
NotFoundError Traceback (most recent call last)
NotFoundError: Key module/MobilenetV2/Conv/BatchNorm/beta not found in checkpoint
[[node save_2/RestoreV2 (defined at /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_hub/native_module.py:451) ]]
```

It also mentions this error

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saving/saveable_object_util.py in op_list_to_dict(op_list, convert_variable_to_tensor)
    286         if name in names_to_saveables:
    287           raise ValueError("At least two variables have the same name: %s" %
--> 288                            name)
    289         names_to_saveables[name] = var
    290 

ValueError: At least two variables have the same name: dense/bias
```

Comment: Can you go through https://coral.withgoogle.com/docs/edgetpu/models-intro/#model-requirements and see if you find something useful ?